# HTML5 videos don't play on iOS devices when served with Apache on OSX Mavericks

Tags: server, video, ios

I'm running Apache as a web server on OSX Mavericks on a home machine.
Videos in the HTML5 `<video>` tag do not play on iOS devices. They do play on other devices (laptop, desktop, OSX, Windows, Firefox, …)

The required `AddType` directives are present in an *.htaccess* file.

The same videos with the same HTML do play on iOS devices if I put them on my hosting service, which also runs Apache.

The sample video in the W3Schools `<video>` tag also runs on iOS, but if I copy that video onto my home server it again fails to play on iOS devices.

The only difference I can observe is that my Apache server runs on top of OSX Mavericks.

The HTML is very simple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<video width="320" height="240">
<source src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4; codecs=avc1.42E01E,mp4a.40.2" />
</object>
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a dump of the headers for the video:

```
$ curl --head cailliaucloud.org/Alphabetical/aa/mov_bbb.mp4
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 17 Sep 2016 12:59:35 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) PHP/5.4.30 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/0.9.8za DAV/2
Last-Modified: Mon, 06 Jan 2014 09:29:01 GMT
ETag: "c080d-4ef49e3d6d140"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 788493
MS-Author-Via: DAV
Vary: User-Agent
Content-Type: video/mp4
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: (the actual url is a little different from the simplified on I used in the question original)

Comment: I think this StackOverflow question has the answers you need:  [HTML5 Video tag not working in Safari , iPhone and iPad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20347352/html5-video-tag-not-working-in-safari-iphone-and-ipad)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **web development** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Web development questions may be asked at [so] but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines.

Comment: this question is about Apache configuration, how is that off-topic?

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I had already followed those but it did not help.  It all works if the files run on Apache on my hosting service, but not if they run exactly the same way on Mavericks' s Apache.  Same htaccess etc.

Comment: I can't answer my question (possibly because it was put on hold) but I found the answer:  iOS will refuse to play back movie files delivered by an HTTPS server with a self-signed certificate.  So I need to get one from Let's Encrypt (or pay through the nose)  Amen.